# Inkscape text on a circle always right to left

Tags: inkscape, text-wrap, text-on-path

I am trying to make a text follow a curve on a circle. But whenever I click "set text to path" the text shows up written from right to left.
I have tried just drawing a simple line (from left to right or frome right to left) always the text is written from right to left.
I tried flipping horizontaly, vertically, turning the object, under no circumstances I can get the text to show up right. Can anybody help me ?
[image: Text on circle]

Comment: I can't replicate this problem using Inkscape 0.92.3.  It works as expected.  What version of Inkscape are you using? I remember reading about a similar bug somewhere a while ago. Can't remember where or when.

Answer (score 1):

I found a useful tutorial video directly addressing your goal.

[Youtube Text on Path video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VwOYO9cAows)

Considering that you've made it this far, the answer boils down to selecting the circle and using the horizontal mirror feature to flip the circle.

The video covers a few other features of text on path that makes the entire video worth viewing for Inkscape beginners.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I had already seen that video, but my problem is not to get the text on the inside or outside of the circle (that works fine with the flip feature). My problem is that the text is always from right to left and no amount of flipping or turning will change that. I am using version 0.92.3. maybe I shall try to update and that will help....

Comment: OK, I just found out that 0.92.2. is the latest version for Mac (which I am using). So no update possible.

Comment: This problem does not depend on Inkscape subversions. It's an issue in your document (probably generated from an imported pdf?). Fix it by creating a new layer and creating your text and circle in that. Or, if you can read German (or use google translate), check out the longer description here: https://vektorrascheln.de/posts/2016/May/inkscape-entdecker-text4.html